# Track RDP user session activity in windows 2003

Tags: event-viewer, windows-server-2003

The users are connected to windows 2003 server remotely through RDP.  At times the users remain connected but inactive with their remote desktop session minimized on their desktop machine.

How can we track the user such as since when the user is logged in? I know one is through the Event viewer Date and Time.  Do we have any other tool to determine logon time?

Is there any tool to determine session activity such as for how long the user has been active or how long the user has been idle?

How is Terminal service manager reliable for monitoring both the logon time as well as the idle time?

Answer (score 0):

I remember I used to use qwinsta/rwinsta commands to remotely kick sessions.  You can query sessions on remote machines using

```
qwinsta /server:[servername or ip]
```

Then  you use rwinsta to reset it.  See more here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/Managing-Terminal-Services-Sessions-Remotely

But that doesn't give you the idle or logon time that you asked for.  Googling around a bit I found one that worked.  I was able to use it from Win8 to query a Win2003R2 machine and it returns the idle time and the logon time:

```
quser /server:[servername or ip]
```

More Info: http://anandthearchitect.com/2008/08/01/how-to-logoff-remote-desktop-sessions-via-command-line-tools/

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind the tool and I am long time RDS/TS expert :-)

Check the [Syskit](https://www.syskit.com/) it can connect to the server and extra info and idle time about all the apps and sessions on the servers. The application is commercial but mention you read about it on the super user and mention me so I will tell guys to provide good discount :-)